# Why my teacher said my sentence wasn't correct?

Tags: grammar

My sentence:

> The Exchange between the teacher and the student promotes learning far different from that which results **as** the student listen but does not participate.

My teacher said "when" is more appropriate than "as" in this sentence, since "as" marks a duration, and "when" an instant or a shorter duration.

I don't understand the difference.

Comment: My first reaction was to think that *as* can also mean *because* or *since*, which would be entirely appropriate in this context.

Comment: It's fine, save for the fact that it should either be "student listens" or "students listen".  "When" would also work, and might be a hair better.

Comment: Off-topic, but 'listen' should be 'listens'.

Comment: I would use "as when."

Comment: Exchange should also not be capitalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a good version: "The Exchange between teacher and student promotes learning far different from that which results when the student listens but does not participate."

I agree with your teacher's judgment, but I'm not sure about the reason.  I suspect that instead of time intervals, what is involved is giving an argument of the verb "result", and "as" does not work for that.  "Result" has two arguments: a cause and an effect.  "Which" is the effect, and "when the student listens but does not participate" is the cause.  "From" would also work here to give a cause -- "... that which results from the student listening but not participating."

"As" doesn't work, because it just introduces an adverb, giving an accompanying circumstance; it doesn't specify an argument.  I'll confess, though, I don't understand why "when" does work here to specify an argument of "result".  But it does.

Comment: My question which portion of a sentence involving "as" should be continuous? Both? The part after "as", the subordinate clause? Or the main clause?

Comment: "As" is like a preposition -- it combines with a following expression, perhaps a sentence, to form an adverbial phrase (as a preposition combines with a following noun phrase to form a prepositional phrase).  "When" is also like this, grammatically.

Comment: So both parts are continuous?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  "Continuous" in what way?

Comment: As in a course of action.

Comment: A course of action referred to by an "as" phrase need not be continuous.  I'm not aware of any relevant requirement here having to do with continuous action.

Comment: Can we said ...has resulted as....?

Comment: No. -----------

Answer (score 2):

"When" refers to a moment/period or "under a certain circumstances" (implicit condition, *if*)

"as" = at the same time that; while. Example: We get wiser *as* we grow older.

In your example, I too believe that "when" is a better choice, because of the condition (*if*) it implies.

Another example:

I'll give it to you when you stop crying - not *as* you stop crying.